# Babel module resolution depending on environment variables?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, metro-bundler

### Project Structure

```
├── project
│   └── operation
│       ├── index.minus.js
│       └── index.plus.js
│   └── index.js
```

#### project/operation/index.minus.js

```
export default (a, b) => (a - b);
```

#### project/operation/index.plus.js

```
export default (a, b) => (a + b);
```

#### project/index.js

```
import operation from './operation';

const result = operation(2, 3);

console.log(result);
```

### Requirement

My requirement is to set an environment variable like **OPERATION_NAME** and based on its value (**minus | plus**) we have to import that particular **`index.${OPERATION_NAME}.js`** into the **`project/index.js`** file.

How to implement this functionality using babel or any other mechanisms?

Comment: `await import("path/to/file" + thiscanIncludeVariables)` can be used for dynamic imports, or just `require` depending on your project.

Comment: But in a bigger project, this pattern would be inefficient right?